# Wordpress Custom Permalinks plugin - Redirect Loop

Tags: wordpress, arabic, permalinks

We have two Wordpress (3.5) blogs in a network setup. We recently installed the Custom Permalinks plugin, https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-permalinks/. It all works fine locally (Mac) and even on production for one of the blogs. For the other blog however, changing the URL slug using the Custom Permalinks plugin, gives: "This webpage has a redirect loop". If it makes any difference (even though it shouldn't) the blog is in Arabic and the posts' URL slugs are in Arabic. I have tried:
- Just going to the permalinks admin pages and hitting "Save", it worked for some people with similar issues.
- Tried to clear cache and cookies.
- Checked .htaccess

**UPDATE**
If this makes any difference, I noticed that on one of the blogs on our production set up, for which I get the "too many redirects" error, if I switch to using English URL slugs, it works. This blog is in Arabic, and we are using Arabic URL slugs.

I am running out of ideas, any help would be much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: There's a problem with the latest version of that plugin. Download 0.7.19 from the developers tab and it should work.

Comment: Thanks Nathan, just tried reverting back to 0.7.19, it didn't fix the issue. I think there is something wrong with our server set up, because locally on our Macs, any version version works for the team here.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is caused by the custom permalink (edited in post itself) having characters invalid for the plugin logistics (even spaces).

The plugin registers a hook:
`add_action( 'template_redirect', array( $this, 'make_redirect' ), 5 );`
template_redirect occurs during template load, as provisioned by the plugin's hook into `add_filter( 'request', array( $this, 'parse_request' ) );`.

Due to plugin not supporting encoded url's, it fails to perform the database query.
The fix was fairly simple enough.
Adding `urldecode()` to the spots required for proper logistics.

**/frontend/class-custom-permalinks-frontend.php**
Line # 167 becomes:
`$request_no_slash = preg_replace( '@/+@','/', urldecode(trim( $request, '/' ) ));`
Line # 369 becomes:
`$request_no_slash = urldecode($request_no_slash);`
Line # 432 becomes:
`substr( urldecode($request), 0, strlen( $custom_permalink ) ) != $custom_permalink`
Line # 440 becomes:
`if ( substr( urldecode($request), 0, strlen( $original_permalink ) ) == $original_permalink`
Line # 441 becomes:
`&& trim( urldecode($request), '/' ) != trim( $original_permalink, '/' )`

solved for me instantly.